# How to distinguish that whether the axis of matplotlib is date or numeric?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
from matplotlib.dates import AutoDateFormatter
from pandas.tseries.converter import PandasAutoDateFormatter


def _judge_date_axis(axis):
    unit = axis.get_major_formatter()
    return isinstance(unit, AutoDateFormatter) or isinstance(unit, PandasAutoDateFormatter)
```

This is my solution, is there any more accurate and directly method?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

A necessary, but not sufficient condition for an axis to be a date axis, is that is has units attached to it. So you can query

```
plt.gca().xaxis.have_units()
```

and if it returns False, it will not be a date axis. The inverse is not necessarily true; just because an axis has units, it does not need to be dates.

In your code you also need to account for a usual `DateFormatter`:

```
isinstance(unit, DateFormatter)
```

possibly a `IndexDateFormatter` as well.